# Get roles through reactions without specifying an ID, so that you can use the command on several servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So far, this is my code. However, this only works on one server. I would like it to work on several servers. I want the ID's through roles that must have a specific name, but unfortunately I only know how to add/remove roles via ID's

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
    let parts = message.content.split(" ");

    if(parts[0].toLocaleLowerCase() == '!rules') {
       
        if(!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.channel.send('Du brauchst die Berechtigung um ein Regelwerk zu schreiben')
        if(!parts[1]) return message.channel.send('Du musst mindestens eine Regel angeben')
    
        var text = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
        message.delete();

        const sayembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('800000')
        .setThumbnail(`${message.guild.iconURL()}`)
        .setTitle('Regeln')
        .setDescription(text, true)
        .setFooter('Erstellt von ' + message.author.tag)
        .setTimestamp();

        let sendEmbed = await message.channel.send(sayembed)
        sendEmbed.react('✅')
        sendEmbed.react('❌')
    }
})

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async(reaction, user, channel) => {

    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

    if(user.bot) return;
    if(!reaction.message.guild) return;

    if(reaction.message.channel.id === '859525260835291157') {
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('854784657857970176')
            }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name of the role, you will need to find the role first. [`guild.roles.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=cache) returns a collection, so you can use the [`find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method. `find()` searches for a single item where the given function returns a truthy value (i.e where `role.name` is the one you want).

```js
if (reaction.message.channel.id === '859525260835291157') {
  if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
    let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Name of the role you are looking for')
    reaction.message.guild.members.cache
      .get(user.id)
      .roles.add(role);
  }
}
```